# Win2D draw single image

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, win2d

I'm able to fill a rectangle with an image and i apply a mask on top of the image using this code

```
args.DrawingSession.FillRectangle(rect, imgRnd, mask);
```

i need to apply some transform to this image, i'am able to do that with no issue, but i have encounter a strange issue, the last pixel is repeated.

i have used

```
imgRnd.ExtendX = CanvasEdgeBehavior.Wrap;
imgRnd.ExtendY = CanvasEdgeBehavior.Wrap;
```

and the image is repeated continuously.

My question is : there is a way to draw one time the image disabling and `ExtendX` and `ExtendY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FillRectangle will always fill all the pixels within the specified rectangle.  The edge behavior enum controls what value they are filled with if the image is positioned such that it does not completely cover the rectangle being drawn.

How exactly are you transforming the image?  Can you change that to also transform the rectangle itself, so you won't be trying to fill pixels that aren't covered by the image?

Another option is to use image effects (Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.Effects namespace) which give much more detailed control than FillRectangle over how multiple images are transformed, combined, etc.